# Date Format Changes when Cassandra UDT data is assigned to python variable

Tags: python, string, dictionary, cassandra

I am beginner in python. I have to retrieve UDT data from cassandra DB and update back with changed value. But on assigning the UDT value when read from Cassandra converts to datetime.datetime() which prevents me to update back to Cassandra.

```
Create Table TblDet
(Col1PK Text
,ColUDT map<text,frozen<typ_det>>
,Primary key Col1PK);

Create Type typ_det
(Ord_St_dt timestamp
,Ord_end_dt timestamp
,process_dt timestamp
,Status     boolean
);
```

Sample Data: Select * From TblDet;

```
 Col1PK   | PK1
 ColUDT   | {'ORD001': {Ord_St_dt: '2017-06-01 05:30:07+0000', Ord_end_dt: '2017-06-10 12:00:00+0000', process_dt: '2017-06-06 00:00:01+0000',Status:FALSE}}
```

Python Code to read values from Cassandra DB and store in dictionary:

```
result=session.execute('SELECT Col1PK, ColUDT FROM TblDet')
for Col1PK, ColUDT in result:
    pythondict[Col1PK]=ColUDT
```

When program executes:

```
print pythondict['PK1']['ORD001']
```

Output:

```
typ_det(Ord_St_dt=datetime.datetime(2017, 06, 01, 5, 30), Ord_end_dt=datetime.datetime(2017, 06, 10, 12, 0), process_dt=datetime.datetime(2017, 06, 06, 0, 0), Status:FALSE)
```

The task is to update based on status retrieved to Status: True and update back to cassandra DB.

If I am able to retrieve the value as stored in cassandra DB,I can assign to string and replace the text, update back to DB. Since values are retrieved in datetime.datetime format, I am unable to handle the operation.

```
str={Ord_St_dt: '2017-06-01 05:30:07+0000', Ord_end_dt: '2017-06-10 12:00:00+0000', process_dt: '2017-06-06 00:00:01+0000',Status:False}
str=string.replace(str,'Status:False','Status:True')
```

Please help is there any pythonic way of handling the task easily.